# Conversion errors from Swift 3.0 to Swift 4.2 at QRCodeReader.Swift

Tags: xcode, swift4.2, xcode10.1

When I tried to Convert Swift 3.0 to Swift 4.2 from Xcode 10.1,I got error at QRCodeReader

Error is

[image]

What I need to do to fix this issue?
After update to pod 'QRCodeReader.swift', '~> 9.0.0'
 Error is like below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the pod to version 9.0.0 for Swift 4.2 support:

```rb
pod 'QRCodeReader.swift', '~> 9.0.0'
```

(or if you don't use CocoaPods, just clone https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReader.swift/tree/9.0.1)

Comment: after change pod version,it is showing error,I edited error photo in question,if u know how to solve plz sugguest me

Comment: Weird error message. Just to make sure, do a Product > Clean then `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` then `pod install` -- see if it changes anything.